# PsyBNC security

Tags: security

Is there any information on the safety/security of PsyBNC? The software/source itself seems to not have been changed since 2005.

Or is there any other multiserver capable BNC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in the past to get an idea of how secure a piece of software may (not) be.
possibly exploitable bugs seen at first, eye-scanning:

- 03-20-07 - Fixed glibc freeze bug
- 11-16-06 - Added a fix for the freeze bug.
- 06-24-04 - A bug was found while terminating an ssl connection from explicitly disallowed ips
- could lead to a denial of service found by b-l-u-b
- 09-26-03 - segfaulted, when the user got kicked (only in 2.3.2-3) found by ICU
- 07-24-03 - segfaulted in killoldlistener, when PSYBNC.SYSTEM.HOSTn was set to '*' system dependent, also dependent, if IPV6 was enabled.
  found by many (about 20 mails *g*)

What I do to stay connected on multiple servers, I keep [irssi](http://irssi.org) in a [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) on my server. [irssi](http://irssi.org) comes with scripting support and has a handful of plugins and a community.

Unless you need a botnet listener I don't see any other reason to use a dedicated bouncer instead of screen+irssi. If you ask me I'll tell you that irc bots were written with file sharing (remember dcc?) and botnets (zombies pingback + payloading) management in mind.

You probably found it already but i'll just mention this [psybnc wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PsyBNC). you can find there links to other bnc software but can't vouch for any.

Comment: Thank you. Having multiserver-support in the bnc would be helpful because then I won't have to deal with it myself in the code for my own bot. I'm not sure what you mean by "botnet" but the purpose of the IRC bot will be distribution of various messages to the appropriate channels/servers - much like Wikipedia does with update messages for atricles.

Comment: irssi has multiserver support